# How to apply a custom style to a control inside of a custom control template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I have a custom control with a `button` in its template. Template is in `my.xaml` file referenced in `themes\generic.xaml`.

In my app, I use two styles for buttons: wide (default, keyless) and narrow (`x:Key="narrowButton"`). They are defined in `myDic.xaml` file.

I want the button in my template to be narrow.

But this doesn't work:

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="/assembly;component/myDic.xaml" />
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type localui:MyControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type localui:MyControl}">
                <Button Style="{StaticResource narrowButton}">...</Button>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

In fact, `MergedDictionaries` in `my.xaml` causes the button to be not shown at all.

What is a working approach to apply the `narrowButton` style to my button?

Comment: The suggested approach works. But if I have two controls, it's not possible to include the `myDic.xaml` in both of the files that are included in `generic.xaml`. Thus, I ended up moving the needed property to the control's dependency property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the code below...

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="/assembly;component/myDic.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type localui:MyControl}">
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type localui:MyControl}">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource narrowButton}">...</Button>
                      </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
          </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```